# Why is my Datetime field not saved?

Tags: nodes, 8

I use the following code to create a node.

```
    $datetime = "2016-08-01 12:30:00";
    $values = array(
      'title' => $data['title'],
      'body' => $data['body'],
      'field_client' => $uid,
      'field_appointment_date_time' => $datetime,
      'type' => 'appointment'
   );

  $appointment = Node::create($values);
  $appointment->save();
```

The problem is that field_appointment_date_time (a Datetime field) is not been saved.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The above code is correct, date time was saved into DB.
the problem is frontend.

frontend expected this format:

```
"2016-08-01T12:30:00", need a "T" as separator.
```

here is how to put that T as separator,

```
\DateTime::format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s"), need a escape character in-front of T.
```

**2016-01-22 update:**

By the way, I have found out in Drupal 8 , correct way to store datetime is follow:

```
1> first , find out current user timezone, \Drupal::currentUser()->getTimezone()

2> $given = new \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime("2016-08-01T12:30:00",$user->getTimezone());

3> $given->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));

4> then get back formated datetime string $given->format("Y-m-d\Th:i:s");
```

Comment: Use the DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT constant.

Comment: For Date only use DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT

Comment: `DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT` is deprecated.

Comment: @Keven Drupal now wants us to use: [DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/constant/DateTimeItemInterface%3A%3ADATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT/8.7.x)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, please try this

```
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2000-01-30');
$newDateString = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(array(
          'type' => 'article',
          'title' => 'The title',
          'langcode' => 'en',
          'uid' => 1,
          'status' => 1,
          'body' => array('The body text'),
          //'field_date' => array("2000-01-30"),
          'field_date' => $newDateString,
    ));
$node->save();
```

I've picked it from here:https://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/64/create-a-node-date-field

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Drupal 8.5.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.5.0) this works a little differently.

Firstly it's good practice to set the **timezone** explicitly so you know what is going on:

- See PHP's [list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
- Get the default time zone using [date_default_timezone_get()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). Please note [drupal_get_user_timezone()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_user_timezone/8.9.x) is deprecated since Drupal 8.8.0 and removed from Drupal 9.0.0.
- Use Drupal's storage timezone [`DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/constant/DateTimeItemInterface%3A%3ASTORAGE_TIMEZONE/).

Set the timezone:

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
// Or
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
// Or 
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE);
```

Then create the date object using the [PHP DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date_time = new \DateTime('now', $timezone);
$drupal_date_time = DrupalDateTime::createFromDateTime($date_time);
```

Or the [DrupalDateTime class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/):

```
$drupal_date_time = new DrupalDateTime('yesterday', $timezone);
```

I like to use `DateTime` (or [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php)) and then pass into the `DrupalDateTime` wrapper. That way native methods are highlighted in the IDE and also date comparisons (e.g. `$now > $somedatetime` [work reliably](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3058010).

Prior to saving the **date/time** you must set the timezone to `DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE`:

```
$drupal_date_time->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE))
```

You can then format the date for storage using the the [DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/constant/DateTimeItemInterface%3A%3ADATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT/) constant:

```
$drupal_date_time->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT)
```

Here is an example based on above use case:

```
$datetime_string = "2016-08-01 12:30:00";

// Get the default timezone
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
// Or set the timezone explicitly to match the $datetime_string
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

// Create the DateTime object
$datetime = new \DateTime($datetime_string, $timezone);

// Optionally convert to DrupalDateTime if you need the custom methods, etc
$datetime = DrupalDateTime::createFromDateTime($datetime);

// Create and save the node
$node = Node::create([
  'type' => 'appointment'
  'title' => $data['title'],
  'body' => $data['body'],
  'field_client' => $uid,
  'field_appointment_date_time' => $datetime
    ->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE))
    ->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT),

]);

$node->save();
```