# Convert a date with format (2017-05-27) to save in node created field

Tags: nodes, datetime

I've been looking around for a little while for what I thought would be a simple question to answer but I cannot seem to find the answer.

The question is: How can I convert a date with the format `2017-05-27` into a Drupal safe format for saving into the database?

I have looked inside `Drupal\datetime\DateTimeComputed` but I'm not sure that is the right place. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay! Looks like I found exactly what I was looking for. For anyone else looking around for the same or similar thing, check out the link below. That's where I found my answer. [Why is my Datetime field not saved?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/229271/14719)

Comment: I think the linked question is for a different kind of date field.

Comment: Hey! @4k4, thanks for that. Your answer is more accurate. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node `created` field is a [Timestamp Field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21TimestampItem.php/class/TimestampItem/8.3.x). Use the php function strtotime() to convert the string to a Unix timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2017-05-27');
```

and store the value in the created field:

```
$node->created->value = $timestamp;
```

You can also use the method [setCreatedTime()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeInterface.php/function/NodeInterface%3A%3AsetCreatedTime/8.3.x):

```
$node->setCreatedTime($timestamp);
```